# Tranformar un Future<List> a List en Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, vscode, google-cloud-firestore

estoy intentando extraer información de FirebaseFirestore mediante un `Future<List>` pero cuando quiero utilizar los datos que hay dentro, en un `List` la incompatibilidad no me lo permite. ¿Cómo puedo transformarla a lista en otra funcion para poder utilizarla?

Código dentro de la función que extrae la información.

```
static Future<List<DataModel>> _getDataFromFirestore() async {

...
...

rootHeight.then((field) {
      if (field.docs.length > 0) {
        field.docs.forEach((element) {
          return element.data();
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: que necesitas hacer,  un método/operación asíncrona siempre retornará un Future

Comment: Transformar el Future que devuelve a un List

Comment: si es asíncrona retornará un Future,  pero puedes interceptar el valor y asignarlo a otra variable, pero no en el return